# How to set folders to Angular-Cli commands?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

This question is about [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) usage.

Is it possible to specify the project folder for running ng commands?

For example:

`$ ng build /home/fadc80/my-first-angular-cli-project`

Additionally...

Is it possible to specify the output folder too?

For example:

`$ ng build /home/fadc80/my-first-angular-cli-project ./build`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible directly to build a cli project when you're not inside the projects folder.

Angular cli quits with a useful error message here:

`You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command.`

But to achieve what you want to do you can go this way:

```
CURRENT_DIR=$(pwd) && \
cd /home/fadc80/my-first-angular-cli-project && \
ng build -o $CURRENT_DIR/build && \
cd $CURRENT_DIR
```

Answer (score 1):

> **NOTE:** This answer does not answer the actual question, but leaving it hear as the build param information may be helpful to those searching and ending up here.

In the file `angular-cli.json` under `apps` is a property called `outDir` which has a default value of `dist`.

You can customize that value to place the output of your build to wherever makes the most sense for your project.

Furthermore; you can specify the value via the command line with the `output-path` option:

```
ng build --output-path build
```

or via the shortcut `o`

```
ng build -o build
```